# Do we need tags for traditional media? Or just one tag?

Tags: discussion, tagging

There was a question about marker use. But the site strongly assumes digital media, intentional or not. So tagging it illustration is misleading a bit, as far as search is concerned.

While markers tag is self eviden. Do we need a super category for traditional media  instead oor something of that effect? What do you think? **Edit** What should such a categorys name be?

I can make the marker category, just wondering out loud.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To quote [**John Maeda:**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Maeda)

> Skill in the digital age is confused with mastery of digital tools,
>   masking the importance of understanding materials and mastering the
>   elements of form.

When you say media, I am assuming you mean tools such as pencils, paper etc, and not telly, radio :) That could be confusing.

I would love to see more "old-school" methods and tools-related questions.  Mainly because they are not tied to one object (software, Photoshop etc). The act of creating visuals are - in my opinion - today too focused on the *second level tools* and too little on an understanding of the *elements of graphic design*.

So therefore, I would like to see tags reflecting this, and I would like to see suggestions to this.

---

"marker" as a category seems a little too specific, as long as we do not have categories that are "higher" up.

Comment: what should the name of such a category be? And yes media like medium like physical tools paper etc. Material.

Comment: Good question! "marker" seems too specific, _unless_ there are higher levels of relevant tags... maybe we could try "pen & paper", "hand-made". We have "sketching", and that might be at least a start.

Comment: ..and to add: I am "old-school" and believe drawing is an essential part of being a graphic designer.

Comment: Excellent answer. I am also thinking about tags... I like "pen & paper", we would have to do a big re-tag for older questions and keep a really close eye on new ones.

Comment: Thanks - yes, we would have to retag, but I will be happy to contribute to that, if we could find some kind of hierarchy for these tools and objects.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say 'traditional media' is too broad of a term. If we're trying to differentiate from digital, we could go with an 'analog' tag. Also broad, but perhaps a better differentiator with digital (after all, 'traditional media' such as newspapers was still mostly digital for the past 3 decades or so).

If we're talking tools, specifically, perhaps 'analog tools' would work. This would encompass all sorts of things...markers, pens, inks, paints, charcoal, printmaking, etc, etc.

Comment: "Media" as in telly, radio is another discussion, methinks (and perhaps worth discussing - particularly in regard as to desktop publishing and magazines). I think "analog tools" are not really intuitive and easy for (new) users to understand. I think we could come up with a better "hierarchy" for pen, paper, canvas etc.

Comment: Perhaps. The catch is that there are digital pens, canvas, etc as well.

Comment: ... :D yes, I know.. that is the crux, really. Finding terms that does not have some sort of use in the digital world. Not an easy question to answer.